# Display Parsed Xml data in to ListView in Android

Tags: android, xml, listview

```
    public class MainActivity extends Activity {

        ListView list;
        EditText name,number;
        Button store,display,update;
        ArrayList<String> fetchData = new ArrayList<String>();
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            name=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.pname);
            number=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.pnumber);
            store=(Button)findViewById(R.id.bSignup);
            display=(Button)findViewById(R.id.bShow);
            update=(Button)findViewById(R.id.bUpdate);

            list=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);
                    try{
                        Time now = new Time();
                        now.setToNow();
                    DocumentBuilderFactory docFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
                    DocumentBuilder docBuilder = docFactory.newDocumentBuilder();

                    // root elements
                    Document doc = docBuilder.newDocument();
                    Element rootElement = doc.createElement("user");
                    doc.appendChild(rootElement);

                    // staff elements
                    Element staff = doc.createElement("details");
                    rootElement.appendChild(staff);

                    // set attribute to staff element
                    Attr attr = doc.createAttribute("id");
                    attr.setValue("1");
                    staff.setAttributeNode(attr);

                    // shorten way
                    // staff.setAttribute("id", "1");

                    // firstname elements
                    Element firstname = doc.createElement("firstname");
                    firstname.appendChild(doc.createTextNode("manjeet"));
                    staff.appendChild(firstname);

                    // lastname elements
                    Element lastname = doc.createElement("lastname");
                    lastname.appendChild(doc.createTextNode("singh"));
                    staff.appendChild(lastname);

                    // nickname elements
                    Element nickname = doc.createElement("nickname");
                    nickname.appendChild(doc.createTextNode("mr. singh"));
                    staff.appendChild(nickname);

                    // salary elements
                    Element salary = doc.createElement("salary");
                    salary.appendChild(doc.createTextNode("100000"));
                    staff.appendChild(salary);

                    // write the content into xml file
                    TransformerFactory transformerFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
                    Transformer transformer = transformerFactory.newTransformer();
                    DOMSource source = new DOMSource(doc);
                    StreamResult result = new StreamResult(new File("/data/data/com.example.xmlparsing/files/Register.xml"));

                    transformer.transform(source, result);

                    System.out.println("File saved!");

                  } catch (ParserConfigurationException pce) {
                    pce.printStackTrace();
                  } catch (TransformerException tfe) {
                    tfe.printStackTrace();
                  }
                    Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this,XMLConcat.class);
                    startActivity(i);

                    display.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View arg0) {    
                        Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this,XMLConcat.class);
                    startActivity(i);
                }
            });
    }


public class XMLConcat extends Activity{
    ListView list;
    ArrayList<String> fetchData = new ArrayList<String>();
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.display_list);
        list=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);
        try {   
            File fXmlFile = new File("/data/data/com.example.xmlparsing/files/Register.xml");

            DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
            DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
            Document doc = dBuilder.parse(fXmlFile);
            doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();

            System.out.println("Root element :" + doc.getDocumentElement().getNodeName());

            NodeList nList = doc.getElementsByTagName("details");

            System.out.println("----------------------------");

            for (int temp = 0; temp < nList.getLength(); temp++) {

                Node nNode = nList.item(temp);

                System.out.println("\nCurrent Element :" + nNode.getNodeName());

                if (nNode.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {

                    Element eElement = (Element) nNode;
                    //at console
                    System.out.println("Staff id : " + eElement.getAttribute("id"));
                    System.out.println("First Name : " + eElement.getElementsByTagName("firstname").item(0).getTextContent());
                    System.out.println("Last Name : " + eElement.getElementsByTagName("lastname").item(0).getTextContent());
                    System.out.println("Nick Name : " + eElement.getElementsByTagName("nickname").item(0).getTextContent());
                    System.out.println("Salary : " + eElement.getElementsByTagName("salary").item(0).getTextContent());


                    fetchData.add(eElement.getAttribute("id"));
                    fetchData.add(eElement.getAttribute("firstname"));
                    fetchData.add(eElement.getAttribute("lastname"));
                    fetchData.add(eElement.getAttribute("nickname"));
                    fetchData.add(eElement.getAttribute("salary"));
                }
            }
            } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            }
        setListAdapter();
}
    private void setListAdapter(){
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,R.layout.list_item,fetchData);
        list.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

}
```

I want to retrieve the xml data in listview.This program show the output only in console but i want to show the output in listview.I am learning How to parse xml document in Android.so do not have much knowledge about it.please guide me.

Comment: You need to create an custom listview adapter to accomplish that. See this tutorial: http://androidexample.com/How_To_Create_A_Custom_Listview_-_Android_Example/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=67&aaid=92

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at these tutorials :

http://www.androidhive.info/2011/11/android-xml-parsing-tutorial/

http://www.androidhive.info/2012/02/android-custom-listview-with-image-and-text/

Answer (score 0):

Use Custom Adapter like this.try this.

```
public class Adapter extends BaseAdapter {

LayoutInflater inflater;
ArrayList<DbResultBean> beanList;
DbResultBean bean;
Holder mHolder;
Handler handler;

public Adapter(Context context,
    ArrayList<DbResultBean> beanList,Handler handler) {
    inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    this.beanList = beanList;
    this.handler=handler;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return beanList.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    View view = convertView;
    if (view == null) {

        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.adapter_result_listitem, null, false);

        mHolder = new Holder();
        mHolder.mtxt_exam_dt=(TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.mTxt_ExamDt);
        mHolder.mtxt_marks=(TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.mTxt_MarksObtn);
        mHolder.mtxt_subject=(TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.mTxt_Subject);
        mHolder.mtxtCourse=(TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.mTxt_Course);
        mHolder.mtxtCollege=(TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.mTxt_College);

        view.setTag(mHolder);
    }else{
        mHolder=(Holder) view.getTag();
    }
    bean=beanList.get(position);
    mHolder.mtxt_exam_dt.setText(bean.getExam_date());
    mHolder.mtxt_marks.setText(bean.getMark_obtain());
    mHolder.mtxt_subject.setText(bean.getSubject());
    mHolder.mtxtCourse.setText(bean.getCourse());
    mHolder.mtxtCollege.setText(bean.getCollege());
    return view;
}

public class Holder {
    TextView mtxt_exam_dt;
    TextView mtxt_marks;
    TextView mtxt_subject;
    TextView mtxtCourse;
    TextView mtxtCollege;

}
}
```